# JS : how to convert a string to JS Object (**NOT** to JSON)?

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing, object

I know how to parse a valid JSON string : `JSON.parse('{"key" : "value"}')`.

But what about a **valid JS object, but invalid JSON**, like : `JSON.parse("{ key : 'value'}")` ?
The example above throws :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token k in JSON at position 2

My actual goal is even trickier. I want to parse a string of a JS object **containing RegEx** (unsupported by JSON but supported by JS) into a JS object :

```
'{ key1 : /val1/g , key2 : /val2/i }'
```

I eventually want to use this object with Mongoose and find documents with it :

```
Model.find({
     key1 : /val1/g ,
     key2 : /val2/i
})
```

I have tried applying a fairly complex RegEx to my String, replacing `/val1/g` with `new RegEx("val1","i")` :

```
str = str.replace( /\/(.+?)\/(g?i?).+?(?=,|})/g , "new RegExp(`$1`,`$2`)" )
```

The `.replace()` operation works and modifies the string the way I want it. It yields :

```
{ key1 : new RegExp("val1","g") , key2 : new RegExp("val2","i") }
```

But when I try to apply `JSON.parse` to it, it still fails because `new RegEx("val1","i")`is not a valid value.

Comment: I hate myself for saying this, but maybe `eval` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed, I didn't think about it. Eval is too powerful :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***If*** you control and can trust the text you're converting, you can use `eval`:

```js
var str = '{ key1 : /val1/g , key2 : /val2/i }';
var obj = eval("(" + str + ")");
console.log(obj.key1);
```

Note that when doing the `eval`, since your expression starts with `{`, you have to wrap it in `()` so the parser knows that's starting an object initializer, not a block.

A couple of notes about `eval`:

1. It allows arbitrary code execution. So you really have to trust the text you're `eval`ing. Don't `eval` user input.
2. Code in an execution context directly containing a call to `eval` basically cannot be optimized, because the JavaScript engine can't know, when parsing the code, what the string will contain. So while I suppose technically it's premature optimization, I'd tuck the above off in a function that you call from your main logic rather than embedding it in your main logic directly.

Comment: That's a big "if" ;-)

Comment: Also, I think it will prevent JIT optimization.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Yeah, I tried to mark it up fairly large. :-) The question suggests that it may well be the case here.

Comment: @EmileBergeron: Ah, yes, it's worth calling that bit out. I'll do that. Unlikely to be an issue, but still.

Comment: Didn't you answer the same question the same way a week or two ago? Or are you getting like me and finding it harder and harder to find old questions and answers, even the ones you wrote?

Comment: For that matter, I can trust the source and use eval. It's only to use in an admin interface. Thanks T.J., you made my day. (I can accept your answer in 6 minutes)

Comment: @torazaburo: I don't *think* I did...but I can't say more firmly than that. :-) But an answer containing `eval` would tend to stick out in my mind...

Comment: @JeremyThille: Glad that helped. `eval` gets a bad rap. It's not evil in and of itself, it's just a powerful tool that can be powerfully misused. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I faced simmilar issue and solved it with the help of split and reduce.

```
const getObjectFromString = (stringToParse) => {
    if(typeof stringToParse === 'string'){
        let currentKey = '';
        const keyValPairArr = stringToParse.replace('{','').replace('}','').split(':');
        return keyValPairArr.reduce((obj,current,index,arr)=>{
            const previousKey = currentKey;
            const arrKeyVal = current.trim().split(',');
            currentKey = index!==arr.length-1?arrKeyVal.pop().trim():'';
            const previousVal = arrKeyVal.join(',');
            if(previousKey&&previousVal!=='')obj[previousKey]=previousVal;
            return obj;
        },{})
    }else{
        return stringToParse||{};
    }
}

// following are some results

const example1 = getObjectFromString('{first : 1, second : 2nd, third: "third, 3rd" }')
console.log(example1) // output: {first: '1', second: '2nd', third: '"third, 3rd"'}
```

It returns either empty object or the converted object from the passed string.